# Как можно сделать ночную тему в Android?

Tags: java, android

Как можно сделать ночную тему в андроид, и как можно сделать переключение между светлой темой и темной нажатием на кнопку?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Гуглим day night theme android - [первая ссылка](http://www.fandroid.info/daynight-nastraivaem-avtomaticheskuyu-smenu-temy-v-android-v-zavisimosti-ot-vremeni-sutok/)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.